# I want create UITabbarController,UINavigationController using delegates

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to create `UITabbarController`,`UINavigationController` by using `UITabbarControllerDelegate`, `UINavigationControllerDelegates`.

Will you please send me any link, or show me how to do it , because i am new to this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some step by step Explanation then you can Go through :

[Putting a UINavigationController within a UITabbarController](http://maybelost.com/2010/12/putting-a-uinavigationcontroller-within-a-uitabbarcontroller/)

And If you want some Detailed Explanation with Screenshots then you can use :

[Tutorial for iPhone app with UITabBarController and UINavigationController](http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/)

To Learn more fundamentally , the best source is [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is very helpful for you, here you can learn how to integrate UINavigationController inside UITabBarController and it is very standard way.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html